# How can I create a frosted glass effect on a fixed backdrop (using position: fixed)?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a modal which has  frosted glass backdrop. Imagine an element that pops up when clicked.

So:
page -> element
Upon clicking on element:
Page -> frosted backdrop -> element

All the solutions I have read online require the use of filter. However, by CSS specifications, `position: fixed` does not work if filter or transform is used anywhere in the parent DOM hierarchy. That is because it creates a new context.

Is there *any* other to create a frosted glass backdrop?

**Update**

This the CSS specification which explicitly mentions that fixed will not work if the *ancestor* has `transform`, `filter` or `perspective`. **In other words, if any item in the ancestry uses blur effect, this will not work.**

> `fixed`
> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no
> space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned
> relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport,
> except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or
> filter property set to something other than none (see the CSS
> Transforms Spec), or the will-change property is set to transform, in
> which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block. (Note that
> there are browser inconsistencies with perspective and filter
> contributing to containing block formation.) Its final position is
> determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.
>
> This value always creates a new stacking context. In printed
> documents, the element is placed in the same position on every page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

In summary, all the solutions I have read online require the use of filter. I need one without (or a way to create a full screen backdrop without using
`position: fixed`

Comment: Have you actually tried this? [reprex]? Because `absolute`/`fixed` positioning works as advertised with filters...

Comment: Updated the question with CSS specs. If you put the modal inside another div that uses filter etc, it does not work.

Comment: I'm confused with your codepen (which by the way you shouldn't hide in a comment under an answer post- your should always [edit] clarifications into your question post). What is it supposed to demonstrate? What's the problem with it? And please- provide a [Stack Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541). Do you actually want the modal itself to have a backdrop filter? Or do you want everything behind the modal in the entire screen to have a filter?

Answer (score 0):

For your frosted backdrop, just create a `position-fixed` element that fills the screen behind your modal dialog that uses the `backdrop-filter` property.

Quoting from [MDN's page on `backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter):

> The `backdrop-filter` CSS property lets you apply graphical effects such as blurring or color shifting to the area behind an element. Because it applies to everything *behind* the element, to see the effect you must make the element or its background at least partially transparent.

Comment: Updated the question with the reference to CSS spec. Please also check my response on Rene van der Lende's answer. You can see the codepen here: https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/YzOWRrd

Comment: @MayurEkbote do it as a stack snippet and put it in your question post. see [ask] and the instructions on providing a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

There may be something wrong in the way you constructed your document with main content and modal, because testing below snippet on Chrome/Edge/Firefox shows nothing out of the ordinary and displays a `backdrop-filter` as advertised.

The snippet shows *four* differently positioned elements

- two inside a `.wrapper`, one positioned `absolute` and the other `fixed`.
- two inside `body`, one positioned `fixed` and the other `absolute`.
- All four are defined with a `backdrop-filter`.

Each 'modal' contains

- `position: relative` content which in turn has an 'absolute' positioned `.modal-content::before` as header.
- All headers too have a `backdrop-filter` defined.

As positioning and filters each create new *stacking context*, you now have an example using at least eight new stacking context, each with their own `backdrop-filter` being *frosted glass* over some content.

I left out the `onclick` mechanism...

```css
:root { --bd-radius: 15px }

.modal {
    width : 50%; height: 50%;

    /*******************************/
    /* Frosting and other graphics */
    /*******************************/
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(3px);

    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%, 0.15);

    border-radius: var(--bd-radius);
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px hsl(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
}

/* Four different locations */
.m1 { inset: 10% auto auto 10% }
.m2 { inset: 20% auto auto 20% }
.m3 { inset: auto 20% 20% auto }
.m4 { inset: auto 10% 10% auto }

/* Distinguish between fixed/absolute */
.absolute { position: absolute }
.fixed    { position: fixed    }

/* Another new stacking context */
.modal-content {
    position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
/* Positioning the modal header */
.modal-content::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;
    content: 'header';
    
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

/************************/
/* just some demo stuff */
/************************/

*, ::before, ::after { box-sizing: border-box }

html { /* responsive main fontsize using y=mx+b */
    font-size: calc(1.25vmin + 4px); /* (320,8)(1280,20) */
    font-weight: bold
}

body {
    margin: 0; background-color: DimGray; color: White;
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/26/1920/1080");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.wrapper { width: 100%; min-height: 100vh }

.content {
    width: 100%; min-height: 100vh;
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: Tomato;
}

.modal, .content, .modal-content {
    display: grid; place-items: center;
    text-align: center; word-break: break-word; hyphens: auto;
}
.modal {
    font-size: 2.5rem;

}
.modal-content::before {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);

    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
    border-radius: var(--bd-radius) var(--bd-radius) 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">some content in the background</div>
    <div class="modal m1 absolute">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>some modal</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal m2 fixed">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>some modal</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal m3 fixed">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p>some modal</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal m4 absolute">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p>some modal</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

A codepen for instant fiddling: [SO75550961, frosted glass](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/YzOWRrd)

Comment: Updated the codepen. You can see that if the modal is nested inside another div that uses filter effect, it does not work.